# Motion-detection alarm - how to make alarm persist?

Tags: voltage, transistors

This is a basic question. I have a motion-detector, but when it detects motion I don't think the output voltage persists. So it can trigger my transistor to trigger a buzzer I have, but after the motion passes all the voltages would die back down and the buzzer wouldn't ring anymore. I want, when the motion trigger happens, for the voltage across the buzzer to persist so that the buzzer keeps ringing until someone manually comes over and turns it off.

How can I make it so that when the trigger happens, the voltages persist?
 Either forever or a really long time (several minutes). Is there a component that would allow this to happen? Would like to avoid using a microcontroller for something this simple. Thanks!

Comment: See if anything in the tag [latch](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latch) helps you, otherwise you might want to add your exact details to the question and get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a latch circuit.

[image]

*Figure 1. A two-transistor latch circuit. Source: [Learning About Electronics](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Latch-circuit-with-transistors.php).*

How it works:

- On power-up both transistors are off.
- When a positive pulse arrives on the input current flows into the base of the lower transistor - let's call that Q1.
- Q1 turns on shorting C to E.
- Current is now drawn from the base of Q2 (which is PNP type) so it turns on too.
- Current now flows through Q2 lighting the LED.
- Current also flows back to Q1's base through the 1k resistor. Now if the original input signal is removed Q2 keeps Q1 on which keeps Q2 on which keeps Q1 on ...

To reset the circuit you just need a normally closed push-button on the positive supply or in the 1k branch.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make it so that when the trigger happens, the voltages persist? Either forever or a really long time (several minutes). Is there a component that would allow this to happen?

Yes. A (near) single-component solution to many of these requirements is called a [Thyristor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thyristor) or [SCR (Silicon Controlled Rectifier)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_controlled_rectifier). This latches current flow through it, until that current drops below a certain "holding" level (or is interrupted completely).

Here is an example of a simple circuit from [Electronics Tutorials](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/power/thyristor-circuit.html):

[image: Example circuit showing thyristor from Electronics Tutorials]

So in that example, current into the Gate (I<sub>G</sub>) is only required briefly, when `S1` is pressed and released. Current through the load and through the Thyristor (I<sub>A</sub>) then starts to flow, and that current continues to flow, even if the current to the Gate is removed.

In that example circuit, assuming that current to the Gate has now stopped, then current to the load (which had latched) is stopped by pressing and releasing `S2`. That works by briefly short-circuiting the Thyristor, so the load current flows through `S2` rather than the Thyristor. That reduces the current through the Thyristor (I<sub>A</sub>) below its "holding current" and "unlatches" the Thyristor.

As an aside - when I was in college, the terms Thyristor and SCR were synonymous. I see that some people claim that the term "Thyristor" only applies to larger devices. I don't know if there is a "correct" answer to that dispute about terminology.